# Plugin: connect to external database without showing password

Tags: plugins, database, password

I am creating a WP plugin, which shows information from an external database. The plugin will be distributed, the external database is on my own server.

I know the following code will connect to my database:

```
$newdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
$newdb->show_errors();
```

But I do not want to show my password to everyone who downloads the plugin. I searched on Google and many forums, but I could not find a way to do this safely.

I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it's rare for a plugin to make a direct DB connection, for the very reason you're citing (among others, like port concerns, DB security best practices, etc.).

In most cases, if you want your plugins to connect to an external data source, it's best to do it using an [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface). So you'd access the information via HTTP, rather than a DB connection.

If the information you're providing to the plugin is *not* sensitive, this is way easy to accomplish: just create an endpoint (yourserver.com/some-info/) that provides the info as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (or some other structured data format like XML). Your plugin can then request that info via a [plain ol' GET request](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get).

If your data is sensitive, or if you need the clients to have write permissions, you'll want to add an [auth mechanism](http://oauth.net/2/) to your API. Users would then need to authenticate, and to provide a valid token in order to access the data.

It might sound daunting at first, but most [good PHP frameworks](http://laravel.com/) make it pretty easy to roll your own API--you just need basic routing, and authentication. And Apigee provides a good (free, in exchange for your contact info) [overview of API design here](https://pages.apigee.com/web-api-design-website-h-ebook-registration.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! I had no experience with XML so far, so that did not come to mind, but it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For others who, like me, found this answer. It's possible to store the login information for the second DB as plugin options via WP settings API. sot the actual login information is not in the plugin but in the WP database.